# "had not done" vs "did not do" in a sentence

Tags: past-simple

> At last, yesterday I listened to this radio show, although I **did not do** it before because I was busy.
>
> At last, yesterday I listened to this radio show, although I **had not done** it before because I was busy.

Which one is the best? I think both are correct perhaps past perfect is better 
even if before indicate clearly the order of the event.

Comment: foget to add do I did not do

Comment: Verb tenses aside, neither of those sentences is correct, because they're both [run-on sentences or comma splices](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/runons.htm).  You can't just ram "yesterday I listened to this radio show" and "I did not do it before" together without a conjunction like **but** or **although**.

Comment: At last, yesterday I listened to this radio show, although I did not do it before because I was busy;                                                                                                       At last, yesterday I listened to this radio show, although I had not done  it before because I was busy;                    better like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At last, yesterday I listened to this radio show, although I did not do it before because I was busy.

"Did not" is a bit more direct. It implies that you recently had a chance to do something, and either were unable to, or chose not to.

> At last, yesterday I listened to this radio show, although I had not done it before because I was busy.

"Had not" is a bit "loose." It implies that you should have done it in the past, but you have not done it up to this point.

## However

I would rewrite this sentence if it was mine.

> At last, yesterday I listened to the radio show

The first part rolls off the tongue uncomfortably. I would shorten it and remove the comma.

> I finally listened to the radio show yesterday

> , although I did not do it before because I was busy.
>
> , although I had not done it before because I was busy.

I would also rewrite the second part, although that is mostly personal preference.

> ; I did not do it before because I was busy.
>
> ; I had not done it before because I was busy.

My final sentences (personal preference):

> I finally listened to the radio show yesterday; I did not do it before because I was busy.
>
> I finally listened to the radio show yesterday; I had not done it before because I was busy.